# Inaccuracy of shazamio library

Tags: python, audio, shazam

I'm working on a program that use the shazamio library to identify song information.

It works great most times but occasionally it fails to identify a song it has identified before so after some trouble shooting its seems sometimes the songs is not recognized when I get my code to loop the recognition a few times it usually figures it out but that really inefficient so looking to find out if they is a more accurate way to search songs data or a way to improve accuracy of the shazamio search just need name of the artist and the songs title.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you wrote for this, together with some examples of misclassified songs.